# Chrome Extension Inject Script and New Tab Issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I built a chrome extension with intention of it changing opacity when a new tab is open it gets darker.

First tab being completely viewable and than increasing to get darker.

**Script.js**

```
var counter = 0;
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback() {

  if(counter>0) {
    grayLayer();
  }
  counter++;
});

function grayLayer() {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
     var opacity = counter * 0.1;

     document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:fixed; background: black; opacity: '+ opacity +'"></div>';

  }
})
}
```

**Manifest.js**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "The Extension",
  "description": "A lovely extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [ "script.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "icons":[
          {
          "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" 
          }
    ],
  "permissions":"tabs",

   "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

I tried to fix the error by adding in "web_accessible_resources":["script.js"] that did not help either.

There are no browser or error codes it just not working or functioning as I expected.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated on way to move forward to get the extension working.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. To access page DOM content scripts are used. One cannot access DOM in background page.

Comment: You need to tell us what is happening that you consider wrong.  You "tried to fix the error". What error?

Comment: In addition to the above, your code alters `document.body.innerHTML` thus destroying event listeners of the page, making it unusable. Did you learn it from some horrible tutorial?

Comment: @yogeshkumar Could you tell me a better approach?

Comment: @Makyen There is error code shown but it does not do what i want it to do that is reduce opacity as tabs opened.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Much appeciated.

Comment: @wOxxOm what do you suggest new approach on how to make it work?

Comment: Make sure to read a short [extension overview: architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and you'll find the answer: content scripts.